# Does sklearn "Nested versus non-nested cross-validation" example code need a "clf.fit(X_train, y_train)"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is the example code from sklearn:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, KFold
import numpy as np

# Number of random trials
NUM_TRIALS = 30

# Load the dataset
iris = load_iris()
X_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target

# Set up possible values of parameters to optimize over
p_grid = {"C": [1, 10, 100], "gamma": [0.01, 0.1]}

# We will use a Support Vector Classifier with "rbf" kernel
svm = SVC(kernel="rbf")

# Arrays to store scores
non_nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)
nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)

# Loop for each trial
for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):

    # Choose cross-validation techniques for the inner and outer loops,
    # independently of the dataset.
    # E.g "GroupKFold", "LeaveOneOut", "LeaveOneGroupOut", etc.
    inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=outer_cv)
    clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
    non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_

    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
    nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()

score_difference = non_nested_scores - nested_scores

print(
    "Average difference of {:6f} with std. dev. of {:6f}.".format(
        score_difference.mean(), score_difference.std()
    )
)
```

In the nested cv part:

```
    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
    nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

Why there is not a `clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)` before `nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)` ?

What I understand is:

```
    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    
    # Find the best parameters
    clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
    best_estimator = clf.best_estimator_

    # or like this
    best_estimator = SVC(**clf.best_param_, kernel="rbf")

    # Then put the best_estimator into cross_val_score
    nested_score = cross_val_score(best_estimator, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)

    nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

I know the official example code must be right. Could anyone please tell me why my understanding is wrong?